# Pass PHP variable in URL query

Tags: php, mysql, url

This is the code placed in `unlock.php`:

```
> <?php require_once("../../db-config.php");
> 
> $Result = "ERROR, still locked..."; if (isset($_POST['User'])) { 
>         if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM LoginAttempts WHERE User='".$_POST['User']."'", $conn))
>                 $Result = "User Unlocked"; } if ($conn)
>         mysql_close($conn); echo $Result; ?>
```

I want to unlock a user, I'm trying like this but getting the error `"Error still locked..."` instead of `"User unlocked"`:

```
http://example.com/unlock.php?User=Administrador
```

How should I pass the variable `User=name` in the URL?

Comment: don't bother, someone will unlock your whole database with sql injection pretty soon

Comment: Use `$_GET` instead of Post. GET if for getting parameters from URL, POST is for data submitted by a HTML form. And yes, you're not save for SQL injections at all.

Comment: as @Twinfriends said just change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: @AmanRawat Yeah it will solve his problem, but it wont change anything that there's no security. SQL injection incoming. He should use prepared statements to avoid this. NEVER put get/post parameter directly into a query.

Comment: For learning prepared statements with PDO use this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: This is code of an old app where a friend works; I'm not trying to change the code. He locks is user and I'm trying to unlock it by doing  a query from the browser. Should I do something different? Thanks for your responses.

Comment: May you should do it with a form (I think thats a backend part of your application..?). Or if you do it with GET, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect your URL params using $_GET. Or [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) (which collects from POST, GET and COOKIE).

Beware that this call:

`http://example.com/unlock.php?User=Administrador' OR 1=1`

will empty your `LoginAttempts` table.

At least sanitize your input with `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['User'])`.

Comment: Apache forbids  the access by using this URI

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by going to PHPmyadmin and deleting the corresponding failed login attempts entries in the db table.

Different approach solves the issue. I've already warned about the security concerns.

Thanks guys.